# Trying to set color point by column value in CartoDB

Tags: mapping, cartodb

This is my first time using CartoDB. My dataset is a simulation of the behaviour of users arround the campus. My rows have latitude, longitude and the class column depending of the cluster in which the user is.

I saw an option to visualize the animation of the behaviour (cartodb transforms the data into a time lapse), but I'm trying to see the points colored by the class value. In the platform, there is an option to do that, but when I choose the "animation" mode then I can't choose any of the columns to set the color.

I show you an image:

[image]

However, if I choose the "By points" mode, I can display the points color by the class column value.

Is there anyone who has had the same problem? Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on the column type, you need your column to be a string to be offered as a value, so maybe you want add a column to your SELECT statement on the `DATA` tab to reclassify your clusters. If you rename then you can also show them on the legend can reflect a better name for your clusters:

```
select *,
       case cluster
         when 1 then 'Cluster 1'
         when 2 then 'Cluster 2'
         else 'unknown'
       end as cluster_named
from my_table
```

Something around that should help to convert `cluster` numeric field into a string one, then you'll see it offered to animate by that value.

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO